# using multiple actionlisteners to change text on same jbutton depending on condition

Tags: java, jdbc, jbutton, jeditorpane

I am trying to create an interactive text based system in java. What the system does is it shows the users a piece of text on a JEditorPane and a list of choices they can choose outputted onto jbuttons. 
like this

```
    JButton btnChoiceA = new JButton("");
    btnChoiceA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent q1ch1a) {
            if(q1ch1a.getSource() == btnChoiceA) {
                try {
                    RetrieveQuestions.story2();

                    lblLocation.setText("Location : "); 

                    storyPane.setText(" " +RetrieveQuestions.story2);
                    lblVariablelocation.setText(" "+RetrieveQuestions.location2);
                    RetrieveQuestions.choice2();
                    btnChoiceA.setEnabled(true);
                    btnChoiceA.setText(" "+RetrieveQuestions.choice2a);

                    //btnChoiceB.setEnabled(true);
                    btnChoiceB.setText(" "+RetrieveQuestions.choice2b);

                    btnChoiceC.setEnabled(false);
                    btnChoiceC.setVisible(false);
                    //btnChoiceC.setText(" "+RetrieveQuestions.choice1c);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("q2 not available");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

At any stage, I should have 3 buttons. However, what i am not sure and if possible adding multiple actionlisteners to the same button since the content of for example button A is "yes" on first story, then if i click A it should bring story 2 and change text on the button (content is gotten from the database and for the first story it is showing just fine)... and so on for a couple of slides/stories.
thanks in advance

Comment: You look like you're changing the text of your JButton in the listener -- I'm not sure what your question is. Please consider creating and posting a decent [mcve] that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: One issue I do see though appears to be tight coupling of your view and your program logic, something that might make debugging and enhancing the program difficult. Consider better model-view separation. Also, consider looking into use of Actions rather than ActionListeners, and swapping a JButton's Action when you want to change its behavior and appearance.

Comment: sorry about that.
anyway... what i was trying to do was to change the the text of the button each time it was pressed and i couldn't think of doing this any other way than what i did above without having to add more buttons to display what i want. initially i have just three buttons

Comment: RetrieveQuestions is a class that's querying the database to give out the content of what should be on the jbuttons

Comment: So...  your question is ? How to change the button's text? behavior? both?

Comment: yes... both... to change the text on the button and to change the behavior

Comment: okay I have managed to get to work as I desired. Thank you for your help... you expanded my horizon